# Duplicate url rewrite for the same product_id

Tags: magento-1.9, products, url-rewrite

i'm new on magento developement.
My "core_url_rewrite" datatable contains 3.000.000 records for 3.000 products.

For a given target_path, i have 1000 records but i dont known why

[image]

Please help. thanks

Comment: Please backup and delete your url_rewrite table and then run reindexing, so new products url will be generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Shoaib Muni @Ludovic Parenty,

There is one annoying problem in Magento – the url rewrite indexer creates tons of unnecessary custom rewrites for products with duplicate url_keys. This happens during every indexer run. As a result, the size of the core_url_rewrite table grows to enormous sizes.

Please note that the problem is typical for Magento 1.7 – 1.9 and its above versions.

I hope this will make sense.